# What is tf/static_transform_publisher equivalent in tf2?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am attempt to migrate everything related with tf to tf2. In my case, I am not sure what is  tf/static_transform_publisher equivalent in tf2?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294926/what-is--tf/static_transform_publisher-equivalent-in-tf2?/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want the tf2_ros/static_transform_publisher.

tf2 is designed to be ROS agnostic (aka no roscpp or rospy) [tf2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros) has all the ROS client library bindings.

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2#ROS_Bindings

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thank you so much.

Can you tell me why my queternion seems invalid:

```
Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "100" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000)
```

?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-06-21**:
It's not normalized. Read more at #q9981 And please don't ask unrelated follow up questions in comments. It's bad for discoverability.

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2018-06-21**:
Okay, thanks. Point duly noted.